# Typescript - AngularJS - Extended Class Not Working

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a Base class:

```
export class VehicleCtrl {
  static $inject = ["vehicleService"];
  constructor(protected vehicleService: VehicleService) {
    "ngInject"
  }

  $onInit = () => {
    console.log("Init")
  }
}
```

Error is in extended class, `$scope` is `undefined`.

```
export class CarController extends VehicleCtrl {

  static $inject = ['$scope'];

  constructor(vehicleService: any, public $scope: any) {
    "ngInject"

    super(vehicleService);
  }


  $onInit = () => {
    console.log("Scope--->", this.$scope)
  }
}
```

Typescript compiler not showing any errors, but in app console scope in undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare all the necessary dependencies in the child and pass them to the parent when calling `super`. Angular will also call the constructor with the arguments in the same order as they are defined in the `$inject` array, so your `$scope` is likely being assigned to `vehicleService`.

```
export class CarController extends VehicleCtrl {

  static $inject = ['vehicleService', '$scope'];

  constructor(vehicleService: any, public $scope: any) {
    super(vehicleService);
  }


  $onInit = () => {
    console.log("Scope--->", this.$scope)
  }
}
```